# How to extract RSA parameters from iOS SecKeyRef?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, cryptography, rsa

I'm calling the iOS `SecKeyGeneratePair` method to generate an RSA key pair. Now I want to extract the RSA parameters from it (both public and private data). How can I do that?

I've found the [CryptoExercise](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CryptoExercise/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008019-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) sample but I don't see that it's actually exporting keys to their raw data. Besides, it's Objective-C which I am really struggling to grok.

I'm doing this in a Xamarin.iOS (C#) mobile app so I need my ultimate solution to be written in C# by calling the necessary interop APIs into iOS (just like my call to `SecKeyGeneratePair`).

For those familiar with Xamarin, yes, I know I can use `new RSACryptoServiceProvider()` to do it much more easily. The difference is 2-3 orders of magnitude perf improvement when I use native APIs for RSA key generation (and even the encryption bit itself). So while I must use native APIs for the RSA work, I also need to get the raw data out so that I can be cross-platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot directly extract the parameters. There was some talk on the Apple developer forums about this (you might want to check). Sadly the [Apple engineer answer](https://devforums.apple.com/message/414922#414922) was the assumptions (about the posted code) were implementation details and subject to change at any time.

Still you *might* be able to do this indirectly using the available API, e.g. export it as a PKCS#12 and then get the RSA parameters from it.

> **UPDATE:** upon verification you can only **import** PKCS#12 - so this would not help *exporting* the private key. I'm back to the *there's no supported way of doing it*. The only safe option, beside the use of managed code, I can think of is to include native code (3rd party library) to generate the keypairs.

I once tried something similar (it was import, not export) but the time required for the extra operations made my code slower than using only C#. Your situation is different so YMMV.

note: it seemed to me that the keychain access (which is out of process, encrypted...) caused much of the slowdown. It was not worth importing a public key for a one-time use - but if you're (re)using it multiple time then the (one-time) cost might be acceptable to you.

Comment: Exporting to PKCS#12 is perfectly acceptable. I'm generating a 4096 bit key which for the managed  implementation can sometimes take hours, so I'm sure the process and export overhead will be trivial compared to native key generation.

Comment: If you have links to how to export the key, please share. Thanks

Comment: Apple documentation might be out-of-date but the documented length limit is 2048 bits - now I know 4096 works (takes about 1min on my 5S) but I can't say if it works on all devices (or before iOS7) https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Link to apple dev's forum post: https://devforums.apple.com/message/414922#414922

Comment: Thanks. I'm fine with targeting just iOS7.

Comment: I've found folks who claim they can export private keys, but Apple says exporting public keys is discouraged, and exporting private keys is very strongly discouraged. So that's... discouraging. :( But dang it, generating a 2048 bit key using managed code takes 38 seconds and in native code takes 3.3 seconds. Since I'm actually going to generate a 4096 bit key, the difference is _much_ more pronounced. So I think I'll have to go either with the strongly discouraged approach, or find a way to use openssl from a Xamarin.iOS app.

Comment: The code from the post should be able to extract both public and private keys (at least it could do it when written). Now **I** can't justify bringing such hack into the Xamarin code base since it would mean any OS update could break existing applications. OTOH nothing stops you from trying the hack first and if it returns invalid data (or an unexpected error code) fallback to the XI/managed implementation (until you update your application). Side note: you're not allowed to call into the openssl library that ships with iOS (but you can include your own copy inside your application).

Answer (score 1):

The `SecKeyGeneratePair` is an older API replaced by `SecKeyCreateRandomKey` that's only available as of iOS 10. So I will answer using the older functions that the question asks about. I'll stick to Core Foundation APIs for interoperability with C#.

You can export the public and private raw key data by adding it to the keychain and returning it as data bytes. Here's an example:

```
//Convert key object into data
SecKeyRef givenKey = publicOrPrivateFromSecKeyGeneratePair;
static const uint8_t publicKeyIdentifier[] = "com.company.myTempRSAKey"; //make it unique per key
CFDataRef publicTag = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, publicKeyIdentifier, sizeof(publicKeyIdentifier));
if (publicTag)
{
    OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
    CFDataRef publicKeyBits = NULL;

    //Create a dictionary info object describing that we are using RSA
    CFMutableDictionaryRef queryPublicKey = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 5, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    if (queryPublicKey)
    {
        CFDictionaryAddValue(queryPublicKey, kSecClass, kSecClassKey);
        CFDictionaryAddValue(queryPublicKey, kSecAttrApplicationTag, publicTag);
        CFDictionaryAddValue(queryPublicKey, kSecAttrKeyType, kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA);
        CFDictionaryAddValue(queryPublicKey, kSecAttrKeyClass, kSecAttrKeyClassPublic); //for public or:
        //CFDictionaryAddValue(queryPublicKey, kSecAttrKeyClass, kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate); //for private
        CFDictionaryAddValue(queryPublicKey, kSecAttrAccessible, kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly); //other options...

        CFMutableDictionaryRef attributes = CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, 7, queryPublicKey);
        if (attributes)
        {
            // Temporarily add key to the Keychain, return as data:
            CFDictionaryAddValue(attributes, kSecValueRef, givenKey);
            CFDictionaryAddValue(attributes, kSecReturnData, kCFBooleanTrue);

            CFTypeRef result = NULL;
            sanityCheck = SecItemAdd(attributes, &result);
            if (sanityCheck == errSecSuccess)
            {
                publicKeyBits = (CFDataRef)result; // Use the RAW key here

                // Remove the temp key from the Keychain
                sanityCheck = SecItemDelete(queryPublicKey);
                if (sanityCheck != errSecSuccess)
                {
                    //... Error deleting temporary public key from keychain
                }
            }
            // else - failsafe code if key exists, try to delete first and then add item etc.

            CFRelease(attributes);
        }
        CFRelease(queryPublicKey);
    }
     CFRelease(publicTag);
}
```

This gets you the raw data. It's raw because it's missing the header that most systems outside of Apple expect. The ASN.1 OID value for RSA public keys followed by a terminating NULL byte, for example.

```
//HEX: 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 01 05 00

/*
 SEQUENCE {
 OBJECTIDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 (rsaEncryption)
 NULL
 }
 */
```

So if you're looking for the raw data you have it. If by "parameters" you're trying to extract the modulus and exponent from the raw data, you can do that too (ex. a bit stream: mod + exp). Let me know if that is what you're after.